# What will happen if Connection close event called inside the Using Statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql

My assumption is if Sqlconnection opened With in *Using* Statement, dispose event will takes place automatically after execution of statement, if i forced  to close the connection with in the Using Statement what will happen is that bad Practice ?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Constring"]))
{
    // SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Constring"]);
    conn.Open();

    String query = String.Empty;
    query = "exec " + StoredProcedure + " " + sampleproc + "";

    using (SqlDataAdapter mainTableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
    {
        System.Data.DataSet mainTableDS = new System.Data.DataSet();
        mainTableAdapter.Fill(mainTableDS);

        conn.Close();
        mainTableAdapter.Dispose();
        conn.Dispose();

        return mainTableDS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using statement does not prevent you from explicitly closing connection. You can still do it but if framework is providing you that facility so you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment @Hakunamatata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There's no need to call both `Close()` and `Dispose()`; calling `Dispose()` will automatically close the connection and dispose of the object.
2. There's no need to call `Close()` or `Dispose()` inside the `using` block.  The `using` statement automatically disposes of the object (and because of #1 above also closes the connection).

Also, a note about #2 above.  It *should* be safe to call `Dispose()` multiple times if Microsoft's [guidance is followed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx):

> If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object
>   must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw
>   an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times. Instance
>   methods other than Dispose can throw an ObjectDisposedException when
>   resources are already disposed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only adding this as an answer because it won't fit in the comments, but in addition to everything in the other answer, you also don't need to call `conn.Open().` The `Fill()` method will take care of it for you. The whole 20 line sample above can be reduced to this brief 8 line snippet without any loss of function:

```
var mainTableDS = new DataSet();
String query = String.Format("exec {0} {1}", StoredProcedure, sampleproc);  //possibly vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks!
using (var  conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Constring"]))
using (var mainTableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
{
    mainTableAdapter.Fill(mainTableDS);
}
return mainTableDS;
```

Comment: Thank you joel for code optimization, and i learned a good one.